# Is it OK to use only special characters in an URL segment?

Tags: url, site-structure

I wanted to separate a section of my website using an URL segment that contains a special (but URL-safe) character like hyphen or tilde, so that some pages would like this: `example.com/-/about` or `example.com/~/about`

Is there any problem (technical or otherwise) this (using **only** a special character - or several - in an URL segment) may cause down the line?

**Note:** I moved the context to [another question](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/101980/correct-ways-of-separating-static-pages-from-main-content) - this seems like a separate concern that I'm still curious about, as I've never really seen it done on a website.

Comment: This is not a good idea for a variety of reasons primary of which is that it does not add semantic value to the URL. Instead, use /definition/about.

Comment: It does seem more _logical_ that the word definition URLs would be of the form `example.com/definition/<word>` (or `/define/` or `/def/` or simply `/d/`) rather than directly off the root as you suggest (`example.com/<word>`), then have all the site pages off the root instead. I imagine that "some" could grow into "quite a few" pages? But maybe having 1000's of `/def/` URLs doesn't fit the bigger picture? I don't think `/-/about` is necessarily bad IMO, it just looks a bit weird.

Comment: Thank you - your comments made me realise this was an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/) and I was asking the wrong thing, so I [moved it to a new question](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/101980/correct-ways-of-separating-static-pages-from-main-content). Still, out of mere curiosity, I'm wondering if this would cause any problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you could do it without any major problems.   The only things I can think of that could go wrong are:

- If you need a directory with that name on your server, it may be difficult to create and work with.   Command line programs use the dash (`-`) to specify flags and special arguments.   They don't like working with files and directories that start with a dash.  The tilde (`~`) often means your home directory and it may get expanded to that by your shell instead of being treated as literal.
- That isn't a "normal" practice and some users may find that it looks odd enough that they might not use your site.
- Those are not keywords, so there is no SEO benifit