# Correct way(s) of separating URLs of static pages from main content

Tags: url, links, site-structure

Let's say I have a dictionary-like website where I have canonical URLs like `example.com/egregious` which displays the definition of the word "egregious".

However, I have a couple of "static pages" that are not really word definitions, like the about page of the website, for which I'm reluctant to use `example.com/about` as that implies to be the definition of the word "about".

I would strongly prefer not to change my main content URLs (word definitions in this example) to something like `example.com/definition/egregious` as that doesn't fit too well with my domain name.

What's the best approach to take here? Several ideas come to mind:

1. Use an URL segment like "pages", e.g. `example.com/pages/about`. This seems a bit strange, since `example.com/pages` seems like an actual word on the website.
2. Use a single character URL segment e.g. `example.com/p/about`. This seems like a less semantic version of the above.
3. Use a special character as a URL segment, e.g. `example.com/-/about`. The validity of this approach is the subject of [my original question](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/101978/is-it-ok-to-use-only-special-characters-in-an-url-segment).
4. Use a special character in the page name itself to differentiate it from a word definition, e.g. `example.com/~about`. This is my favourite at the moment.

Are there any problems (technical or otherwise) with any of these? Are any of them in any way better or worse than the rest?

Comment: With your static pages, why not use the absolute URL e.g. example.com/about.php

Comment: Your suggestions of pages, p, ~, and - add no semantic value. I am suggesting that you add semantic value. This answer may help to clarify things: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/74633/well-structured-urls-vs-urls-optimized-for-seo/74639#74639 The reason why adding semantic value is so important is because it is ***such an important signal*** to the search engines and tells the search engines what your content is about. Please, do not miss this opportunity. Cheers!!

Comment: Related: [User profile URL design](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/86689/17633)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be honest, I think this is really just going to boil down to personal opinion.

> e.g. `example.com/~about`. This is my favourite at the moment.

However using a tilde (`~`) in such a way *could* end up conflicting with [Apache's per-user web directories](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/en/howto/public_html.html) which is common on shared Apache servers.

> `example.com/pages/about`

With using an additional path segment, would users expect to be able to request `example.com/pages` (or `example.com/pages/`)? This, of course, doesn't need to be a valid resource.

Other than that, it would seem to be just making the URL a little bit longer/complex than it needs to be, which probably isn't a big deal.